# Show user's posts in Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass error:
Posts controller:

```
def liked
 @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
 @posts = @user.posts
 render action: :index
end
```

Index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to post.user.username, liked_posts_path(post.user.username) %>
```

Comment: `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])` so this returns nil.  So you don't have a user with that username, or you've not passed the username as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass username to params by setting it in the route

```
<%= link_to post.user.username, liked_posts_path(username: post.user.username) %>
```